# Reuse the output of pander_return in knitr document

Tags: r, knitr, pander

I am working on a package that helps automate exploratory data analysis by creating a knitr file with basic statistics about each column of a dataframe. One issue I've run into is storing the result of a `pander_return` call in a function and then using that output later in a knitr document. A quick example below of the issue in a markdown file:

````
```{r, results='asis', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

require(pander)

x <- pander_return(head(cars))
cat(x)

```
````

I'm having a lot of trouble outputting `x` in a readable way. I've tried various forms of `cat` and `print`. For example, the code above produces the following output:

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8pm.png) “————–speed dist ——- ——4 2 4 10 7 4 7 22 8 16 9 10 ————–”
>   attr(,“class”) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8pm.png) “knit_asis” attr(,“knit_cacheable”) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8pm.png) TRUE

I would like to be able to see a standard output, like the one produced by:

````
```{r, results='asis', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

pander(head(cars))

```
````

I've attached a screen shot as well.

[image: Screenshot of issue and desired output]

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you knitting to `latex` or `html`? If you want to knit to `latex` the `library(xtable)` helps a lot. For tables in html, you can always go play with the css code for the tables it outputs

Comment: I am currently knitting to HTML. However, the output of pander_return doesn't even register as a table to begin with. It just comes out as the block of code in the original question.

Comment: Have you tried `print(x)` instead of `cat(x)`?

Comment: I think you are looking for `cat(x, sep = '\n')` -- but can you please describe your use case? I am really interested in learning about why do you want to store the markdown lines for future printing.

Comment: @CL. Yes, I tried print(x), I updated the screen shot to show the output. Still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @daroczig, I have tried to do that as well, with no luck as well. The updated screenshot shows the output. The use can be seen in my package that I'm working on: [github](https://github.com/vitallish/eda/tree/master/edaR) . The idea is to create standard tables/ statistics for each column in a dataframe in one fell swoop. In order to accomplish this in a simple function call in a knitr document, I need to be able to store formatted text and then print it later. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what the problem is: set `panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)` to be able to use the old-school "asis" output as mentioned in the last part of [pander in knitr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/vignettes/knitr.html) (and use `cat(..., sep = '\n')`. And thanks for the details, @vitallish, I will try to grab some time later today to check your package and try to come up with a way to avoid this hack.

Comment: Thanks @daroczig. In fact, by setting the `panderOptions` as you described I don't have to save the output using `pander_return`, it really helped cut down on my code complexity. If you are curious, you can see it here: [github pull](https://github.com/vitallish/eda/pull/2/files).

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for the feedback @vitallish. Left a comment on the PR with a suggestion to use some other helper functions from `pander` in your pkg :)